# Need to print current CPU usage and Memory usage in file continuously

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have prepared the below script, but it's not adding any data to the output file.

My intention is to get the current CPU usage and Memory usage and print them on log file.

What is wrong with my below script? I will run this script file in CentOS machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
mkdir -p /root/scripts
LOGFILE=/root/scripts/xcpuusagehistory.log
touch $LOGFILE

a=0;
b=1;
while [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
do
    CPULOAD=`top -d10 | grep "Cpu(s)"`
    echo "$CPULOAD on Host $HOSTNAME" >> $LOGFILE
done
```

Comment: `top` is never exiting.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
while true
do
    cpu_load="$(top -b -n1 -d10 | grep "Cpu(s)")"
    echo "$cpu_load on Host $HOSTNAME" >> "$log_file"
    sleep 1
done
```

See top [batch mode (-b)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) in the man page.